# How to build from my checkout directory ... with a twist

Tags: grails, maven, maven-3

We're using Maven 3 with Git as our SCM system.  We are using the latest version of the scm plugin (1.5).  Our project is in Grails 1.2.1 (Java 1.5).  The question is, how do I run a single command to generate a WAR file after doing a checkout from our repo?

This question seems complicated by the fact that we're using the a Grails project (and hence the maven-grails plugin, version 1.3.4).  Grateful for any info you have, - Dave

Comment: Sorry, is it about Maven, or `grails war` will do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the command line below below wont work for you because of your requirement to use maven.

```
grails <environment> war
```

You can generate a pom.xml for your existing grails project with the following command. This can be a useful starting point.

```
mvn grails:create-pom
```

More documentation about grails's maven integration can be found here: 
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.5%20Ant%20and%20Maven